# The definite article before the word "precedent"

Tags: articles

Why is *the* used before the word *precedent*, even though there was no information as to *which* precedent was meant?

> Judicial restraint is the idea that the judges must pay close attention to *the* precedent when they make decisions.

Wouldn't it be better to use *a* precedent in that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speaker/writer has in a mind a situation in which a judge is presented with a precedent.  In the context of that situation, it is *the* precedent, the one to which the judge must attend.

However, "the judges" is not the idiomatic way to refer to "judges in general".

A better way to state things is:

> Judicial restraint is the idea that judges must pay close attention to
>   precedent.

Plural "judges" without article means "judges in general" and singular "precedent" without  article means "the concept or notion of precedent", or "previous decisions that fall under the rubric 'precedent' ".